# Embedding fonts in iPad

Tags: css, ipad, uiwebview, embedded-fonts

I am trying to embed Google fonts in a WebView in iPad.

If I put this in the head all works fine:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monofett' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

The html is local then I need to copy the CSS and the fonts in my iPad.

When I do this changes the fonts doesn't work:

html:

```
<link href='fonts/fonts.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

fonts/fonst.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Monofett';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Monofett'), url('http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/monofett/v1/94n9d8-lEEaOz-Sn4plHGPesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff') format('woff');
}
```

I know I'm still doing remote connections but why doesn't work this?

The web looks fine in Safari and Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the woff format. Google know that and he return you a different css when you use Safari in PC or in iPad. The correct CSS is:

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Monofett';
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: normal;
 src: local('Monofett'), url('./BezoWS-9nng_g31KmAteQ3YhjbSpvc47ee6xR_80Hnw.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Boy, have I got a great answer for you! I had the same problem and this worked like a charm.

You have to use the Google API loader. Here's the code I put into my header tag.

```
<!-- Google API Loader -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //load jQuery
    google.load("jquery", "1.7.1");

    //Google Fonts
    google.load("webfont", "1");

    google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
        WebFont.load({
            google: {
              families: [ 'Lobster+Two:700italic,700,400italic,400', 'Alegreya:400,400italic,700' ]
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is some info about the API loader:
https://developers.google.com/loader/?hl=ja#intro

And some info about using it with Google Fonts:
https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader

Comment: Webfont loader is supported from iOS 4.2 and up, so this would not work for an iPad1.

Comment: @Bjorn. Not true.  iPad1 is not limited to iOS 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an cwTeXHei version , for support google web fonts on iPhone browser

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'cwTeXHei';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('cwTeXHei'), url('./fonts/cwTeXHei-zhonly.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

the url will begin at css folder.
This works on ios 10 safari
thanks Brais Gabin.